# Javascript scroll event with slow response in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, scroll

This function is working fine in Chrome but in I.E the css changes are slow, so is visible to the user when it shouldn't. I am thinking the problem could be with the scroll event or something but I can't solve it... Anyone can help me please?

```
        var freezeLeft = settings.left > 0 || settings.leftClass !== null;
        var freezeRight = settings.right > 0 || settings.rightClass !== null;

        parent.scroll(function () {
                var scrollWidth = parent[0].scrollWidth;
                var clientWidth = parent[0].clientWidth;
                var left = parent.scrollLeft;

                if (freezeLeft) {
                    settings.leftColumns.css("left", left);
                }


                if (freezeRight) {
                    settings.rightColumns.css("right", scrollWidth - clientWidth - left);
                }

        }.bind(table));

    }
```

Comment: Use a throttle function. This way you can reduce the load on the browser. http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/

Comment: You're also doing a lot of calculations on every scroll event. Try only calculating things that will change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response @evolutionxbox , I need to do always this calculations... About the throttle function, I tried to set a timer because I failed to use the throttle but it didn't work . Isn't a timer and the throttle the same thing?

Comment: Sort of. The throttle gives you more control than a timeout and doesn't need to be cleared.

Comment: Alright but that set's a limit to the event per ms right? In this case I want to be very responsive beacause I want that a element changes position on every time the user uses the scroll.